# How to "move" specific old emails from one Gmail account to another?

Tags: email, gmail

I have an old Gmail account, and I need to move **only some** emails from this old account to a new Gmail account. There are many tutorials that show how to move **all** old emails using POP3 forwarding, but I can't find any instructions that guide me to *select* old emails and forward them.

Note that when I mean "forward", I mean to move them to the new mail account as they are in the current state, i.e. no "Fwd:" in the subject and the email sender must remain the original email's sender.

I know this is possible because a browser extension named "Multi Email Forward" by CloudHQ allows this, but it's only available if one upgrades from a free account (which I can't afford).

Comment: Configure an email client for both accounts using IMAP.  At that point, you just move the emails from one account to another (normally drag and drop action).